# Django won't run on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get Django 2.2 to run on Apache 2.4 with Python 3.7 on a Windows 2016 Server. Django runs fine on the development server (manage.py runserver) and the Apache Server runs and is reachable on the network but Django doesn't run on Apache. This is the Apache config (httpd.conf) I'm running:

```
ServerName localhost:80


<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

LoadFile "c:/program files/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/program files/python37/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/program files/python37"
WSGIScriptAlias \ "D:\Django\myproject\myproject\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "D:\Django\myproject\myproject"

<Directory "D:\Django\myproject\myproject">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None    
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

Here's my wsgi.py (not changed from what was generated during manage.py startproject):

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I try to load http://myserver in the browser, I get the Apache Defualt page, but If I try to load http://myserver:8000 I get a connection error.

Edit:

Here are the relevant entries of error.log:

```
[Fri Feb 08 11:30:15.853857 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 864:tid 436] mod_wsgi (pid=864): Python home c:/program files/python37.
[Fri Feb 08 11:30:15.853857 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 864:tid 436] mod_wsgi (pid=864): Initializing Python.
[Fri Feb 08 11:30:15.869484 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 864:tid 436] mod_wsgi (pid=864): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Feb 08 11:30:15.885109 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 864:tid 436] mod_wsgi (pid=864): Adding 'D:\\Django\\myproject\\myproject' to path.
[Fri Feb 08 11:30:15.885109 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 864:tid 436] mod_wsgi (pid=864): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
```

Looks like it loads fine, but it doesn't even try to listen on port 8000.

Edit2:

So my setting for WSGIScriptAlias seems to have been wrong. Now it's at least trying to load the WSGI app.

```
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.123312 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 856:tid 1212] mod_wsgi (pid=856): Create interpreter 'localhost|/test'.
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.138940 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 856:tid 1212] mod_wsgi (pid=856): Adding 'D:\\Django\\kte_test\\kte_test' to path.
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.138940 2019] [wsgi:info] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858] mod_wsgi (pid=856, process='', application='localhost|/test'): Loading Python script file 'D:/Django/kte_test/kte_test/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858] mod_wsgi (pid=856): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/Django/kte_test/kte_test/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858] mod_wsgi (pid=856): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Django/kte_test/kte_test/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "D:/Django/kte_test/kte_test/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     self._setup(name)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 107, in __init__\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Fri Feb 08 12:28:02.310819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 856:tid 1212] [client 172.16.27.254:51858] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'\r
```

Where do I find the missing module?

Comment: Change your apache LogLevel to debug in conf file and monitor the apache error_log files. Paste the corresponding error logs here in order to provide you a better solution.

Comment: As per your edit, why are you hitting http://myserver:8000 ? First add a test ServerName like myserver.test.com and just hit http://myserver.test.com

Comment: @Abijith Mg I can reach http://myserver and I can view a test page I put in C:\Apache24\htdocs It's just Django that doesn't work.